# Data is not reflecting back on Firebase Console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created an account in Firebase and created a project. I have also configured it properly as per the given setup instructions inside the website.

Now when I have written this code , then it is not actually reflecting the changes done in the database.

MainActivity.java

```
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DatabaseReference db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        String userId=db.push().getKey();
        User u=new User("shikher","shikher.mishra@yahoo.com");
        db.child(userId).setValue(u);
```

This code when executed on the emulator is not reflecting anything on the Firebase Console.How to fix this up?

Comment: Have you tried that on a real device ?

Comment: Add a [CompletionListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener) to `setValue()` to see why it is failing.

Comment: User u=new User("shikher","shikher.mishra@yahoo.com");
        db.child(userId).setValue(u).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<Void> task) {
                sync.countDown();

            }
        });
        try{
            sync.await();

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("there is an exception here in sync.await()");
        }

Comment: Now I am getting this error:Probably not a portal: exception java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/172.217.21.206 (port 80) after 10000ms

Comment: Did you get it to work?